# Embedded Quicktime movie not displaying in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, quicktime

I have a .mov file embedded in a web page, using nested object and embed tags.

It displays fine in Firefox & Chrome, but just displays a Quicktime icon with a question mark over it in IE6-8.

Before it displays the icon, it runs the quicktime activex control and flashes the beginning of the movie up.

Any ideas on what could be the issue? I've tested that I have Quicktime and the Quicktime browser plugin correctly installed, and I can view other quicktime movies inside of IE8.

I suspect that it is the movie itself, but it still plays fine in Firefox and Chrome.

If I go to the file directly in IE, it runs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have blocked Quicktime Activex or object tag is bad formed for IE try view source another website with Quicktime that work in IE and FX and download source code from view html

Or else you can use it
[JW Video](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats) an [File Streamer Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/h264.html)

Comment: ActiveX is not blocked, as I receive the prompt about loading the activex plugin and allow it to load.

I've reviewed the object tag, but I'll check again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Quicktime plugin is just tetchy sometimes, so I ended up converting the file to Flash and posting it that way.